# Enabled MTOM in CXF but cannot upload large file

Tags: java, jax-ws, cxf

I am using CXF 2.3.9 to create an upload web service. Here is a fraction of my server bean

```
@XmlType
public class FileUploader
{  
  @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")
  private DataHandler Dfile;
}
```

My `cxf.xml`

```
 <jaxws:endpoint id="uploadfile"
                  implementor="com.ibm.uploadservice.UploadServiceImpl"
                  address="/UploadWS">
                  <jaxws:properties>
      <entry key="mtom-enabled" value="true"/>
    </jaxws:properties>
```

When wsdl2java.bat generate files, I see that my DataHandle type is converted to byte[]. I changed them back into DataHandle and import the necessary library.

When I run my client, I got the following stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.ByteArrayOutputStreamEx.readFrom(ByteArrayOutputStreamEx.java:75)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Base64Data.get(Base64Data.java:196)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Base64Data.writeTo(Base64Data.java:312)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.text(UTF8XmlOutput.java:312)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.leafElement(XMLSerializer.java:356)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$PcdataImpl.writeLeafElement(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:183)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.writeLeafElement(TransducedAccessor.java:256)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:361)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:361)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:333)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:76)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:251)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.writeObject(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:550)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:232)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:169)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:544)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:341)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:294)
```

How can I fix it? Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid if you are following [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-devaxis2part3/section3.html)

You need to remove the lines below:

```
factory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```

Add the following code to the client

```
Map<String,Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
props.put("mtom-enabled", Boolean.TRUE);
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();

factory.setServiceClass(UploadSEI.class);
factory.setAddress("http://localhost:8080/CxfService/UploadWS");
factory.setProperties(props); 

UploadSEI client = (UploadSEI) factory.create();
```

Try to put jaxb-api.jar and jaxws-api in the classpath above your jre library if you are using Eclipse, endorsing does not work for me.